# GWT ValueListBox conform to MVP

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

I am trying to figure out which one of these will conform better to the MVP pattern.

Let's say in my ViewDesktopImpl class I have the following code:

```
class ViewDesktopImpl implements View {

  ValueListBox<Object> valueListBox
}
```

Now, here's what I'm wondering.  Would it make more sense to do the following:

1. Have a HasConstrainedValue getter in my View interface, the Presenter calls getHasConstrainedValue and populate it
2. Have a setValues(List objects) in my View interface, the Presenter calls view.setValues and the ViewDesktopImpl handles populating the valueListBox

I believe it would be better to take Option 1 I would just like to get pros and cons for this - and yes it may be a subjective pattern but I'd like to get some other opinions and reasons as to which option should be taken and how it conforms to the MVP standard.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to implement ListBox as MVP. Look at the [SelectOneListBox](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/selectonelistbox-for-use-with-gwtmvp/) from `David Chandler`. If your question is not related to a specific widget, I would say having a getter and a setter is a good approach. Look at `HasText` interface.

When it comes to testing your presenter, you would mock your view to set your test data using `Mockito`:

```
@Mock
MyView view;

List testValues = ...;
when(view.getValues().getValues()).thenReturn(testValues);
result = presenter.method(...);
assertTrue(result == expected);
```

The view is defined as:

```
public interface MyView extends View {
  HasValueList getValues();
}

public interface HasValueList {
  void setValues(List objects);
  List getValues();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do my MVP.

Instad of having my presenter call getters in my view I have my view call my presenter's methods. This way the business logic is isolated to the presenter and is easily testable without having to mock the view.

```
public interface MyView extends View {
  void setObjectsList(List<Object> objects);
  void setPresenter(Presenter presenter);

  interface Presenter {
    void handleObjectSelected(Object object);
  }
}
```

Presenter implements MyView.Presenter:

```
class MyPresenter implements MyView.Presenter {
  private final MyView myView;
  private List<Object> objects;

  public MyPresenter(MyView myView, List<Objects> objects) {
    this.myView = myView;
    this.objects = objects;  
  }

  public void initialize() {
    myView.setPresenter(this);
    myView.setObjectsList(objects);
  }

  @Override
  public void handleObjectSelected(Object object) {
    // Do something with selected object.
  }
}
```

Example MyView implementation:

```
class MyViewImpl implements MyView {
  private Presenter presenter;
  ...

  @Override
  public void setObjectsList(List<Object> objects) {
    // Do something with object list.
  }

  @Override
  public void setPresenter(Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
  }

  public void somethingHappened() {
    presenter.handleObjectSelected(object);
  }
}
```

Second implementation example of MyView using a ListBox:

```
class ListBoxMyViewImpl implements MyView {
  @UiField ListBox listBox;

  private Presenter presenter;
  private List<Object> objects;

  public MyListBoxView() {
    objects = Lists.newArrayLists();
  }

  @Override
  public void setObjectsList(List<Object> objects) {
    this.objects = objects; 
    listBox.clear();
    for (Object object : objects) {
      listBox.addItem(object.toString());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void setPresenter(Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
  }

  @UiHandler("listBox")
  void onChange(ChangeEvent e) {
    presenter.handleObjectSelected(objects.get(listBox.getSelectedIndex());
  }
  ...
}
```

This way you don't need to mock your view to test the presenter logic.

Instead of:

```
@Mock
MyView view;

List testValues = ...;
when(view.getValues().getValues()).thenReturn(testValues);
result = presenter.method(...);
assertTrue(result == expected);
```

you would test your presenter logic:

```
List testValues = ...;
assertEquals(expected, presenter.method(testValues));
```